# Understanding forerunner to-do tutorial?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at the Forerunner to-do tutorial (http://www.forerunnerdb.com/tutorial/todoList.html) and am having difficulties duplicating its results. I understand the tutorial might be running on Node, and thus dependencies such as jsviews and jquery might not necessarily show up on the index sample page. However, there are problem areas that I do not understand. For instance, this section:

```
    <!-- Create a DB instance and store it globally -->
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.fdb = new ForerunnerDB();
        db = fdb.db('test');

        // Ask forerunner to load any persistent data previously
        // saved for this collection
        db.collection('todo').load();
    </script>
```

Leads to errors, where `fdb` is not a function and `db` is not defined. I make sure to place this JavaScript code after the dependencies are loaded in, namely `fdb-all.min.js`, but I still get errors.

At the moment I am replicating the code on the finished products section, but adding the jsviews and jquery dependencies with the main `fdb-all.min.js`. Thus, my code looks the same as the example in the tutorial, yet doesn't run.

I am also running this in a non-HTTP environment, which should not be a problem because I have a separate example that works while running on my Desktop.

**EDIT**:

If it helps, this is my code verbatim.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First ForerunnerDB Todo App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Include the whole forerunner system, bells, whistles and kitchen sink -->
<script src='http://www.forerunnerdb.com/js/forerunnerdb/dist/fdb-all.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://www.forerunnerdb.com/js/forerunnerdb/dist/fdb-autobind.min.js'></script>

        <!-- Create a DB instance and store it globally -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
            window.fdb = new ForerunnerDB();
            db = fdb.db('test');

            // Ask forerunner to load any persistent data previously
            // saved for this collection
            db.collection('todo').load();
        </script>

        <!-- Define a todo item template -->
        <script type="text/x-jsrender" id="todoItem">
            <li data-link="id{:_id}">
                <span>{^{:text}}</span>
            </li>
        </script>

        <!-- Create an element where our todo items will be output -->
        <ul id="todoList"></ul>

        <!-- Create our item entry form -->
        <form id="todoForm">
            <input id="todoText" type="text" placeholder="Enter todo item" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Item" />
        </form>

        <!-- Use jQuery to hook the onsubmit of our form -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
            $('#todoForm').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the form's todo item text
                var itemText = $('#todoText').val();

                // Add the new item to ForerunnerDB's todo collection
                db.collection('todo').insert({
                    text: itemText
                });

                // Now we've added the item to the collection, tell
                // forerunner to persist the data
                db.collection('todo').save();
            });

            $('body').on('click', '#todoList li', function () {
                // Get the item id for the todo item clicked on
                db.collection('todo').remove({_id: $(this).attr('id')});
                db.collection('todo').save();
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Finally we tell forerunner to data-bind the collection to the todo list -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
            db.collection('todo').link('#todoList', '#todoItem');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you'd show how exactly you're loading the dependencies. The error `fdb is not a function` cannot be from this snippet, as `fdb` is not called as a function anywhere in it. You could start by checking `typeof ForerunnerDB` to see if it's indeed defined and accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and the problem is you're including the scripts from a remote server (that's not a cdn). Downloading the Forerunner scripts and including them locally made everything work.

Comment: Could you upload your page? I replaced the Forerunner script with local, and now get `db.collection.link()` is not a function. EDIT: No need. Got it. Thanks so much guys!